# What does to_route('route_name') mean in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I saw this in this tutorial:

```php
return to_route('route_name');
```

Does `to_route('route_name')` mean the same as `redirect()->route('route_name)`?

I tried finding an explanation in the Laravel docs, but couldn't find it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-to-route) states, `to_route` does redirect, so it should be the same as `redirect()->route('name')`.

You can also check the [official source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/c59d540ab142d36ee0f62c3ddc749329a968466b/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L886-L889), I will copy-paste the code:

```
function to_route($route, $parameters = [], $status = 302, $headers = [])
{
    return redirect()->route($route, $parameters, $status, $headers);
}
```

So, you can see, it is literally a redirect as you posted.

ALWAYS check the official source code, and you will (most of the time) understand and see what some code does